# RegEx Replace to Backspace in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am trying to replace multiple chunks of code here and do it quickly as it's mostly repeated with few differences. I think I have the correct pattern....

```
\t\tMenuKey = \"([A-Z_a-z]+)\",
```

Where MenuKey is any table key I want to remove (as I am making this into an array) and the rest of it should match whatever is the " ", sections...if that's wrong, let me know. But I can't figure out how to make it backspace or essentially remove the entire line in the replace part. I am using Notepad++ and I have it on RegEx...so ideas?

***I want to remove the entire line and have it backspace so it's not there.***

Sample input:

```
    "strings and stuff here",
    MenuKey = "Some_key_Info_here",
```

desired output...

```
    "strings and stuff here",
```

Comment: Please share some inputs along with expected output.

Comment: Ok....I mean having it replace anything on the current line after the = works  too...sample input....

Comment: is there a case where there is nothing after = in that it wont work as + is used. use * instead which says 0 or more occurences

Comment: Edit your original post and add some input examples with the expected output...

Comment: Nope, anything with an = has something after it...my main problem is I don't know how to replace it with a backspace and not something like \b as it just puts a b

Comment: Simply search for [\s]*Menukey = \"[A-Z_a-z]+\" and replace with nothing in notepad++. It will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find by -->     [\s]+MenuKey = \"[A-Z_a-z]+\"
Replace with --> type nothing in the notepad++.

I tried it please find the below image

[image: Before Replacing]

After Replacing
[image: After Replacing]

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
"[A-Z_a-z ]+",\K\s+MenuKey =[^\r\n]+
```

and replace with an empty string

[image]

/!\ Make sure you're using a newest version of Notepad++

Comment: There is no need to search the strings before the required replacing pattern. We can directly search what is desired and replace by nothing

Comment: If he mentionned it, then it might be needed... What if the line before `MenuKey` isnt between `"` ?  But, I must agree that the question is lacking details... As always ;-)

Comment: Ya true. Let him clarify the input. But it is always better to search for what is required. right???

Answer (score 0):

Use find and replace. You find your expression, and replace with a blank field.

I don't think that the double quotes need to be escaped. Also, the parenthesis look redundant.

Your expression might not be matching anything. Click find, and it should take you to an instance that it will replace.

Comment: CTRL+F. Click on the replace tab. Copy and paste the regex into the find field. Leave replace field blank. Click find to find the next expression. Click replace to delete it. If you want to remove all, click replace all. I just tested your example in my notepad++, and it worked. Unless I am missing something...